# Updating a form value returns undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

This is my component code

```
this.participantForm = this.fb.group({
      occupation: [null],
      consent : new FormGroup({
        consentBy: new FormControl(''),
        consentDate: new FormControl(new Date())
      })
 })
```

This is the html

```
<form [formGroup]="participantForm">
    <div formGroupName="consent">
          <label>
            Name:
            <input type="text" formControlName="consentBy">
          </label>
          <label>
            Date:
            <input type="text" formControlName="consentDate">
          </label>
        </div>
        </form>
```

On submit I need to format the Date value.

```
 get pfc() {
    return this.participantForm.controls;
  }
this.participantForm.patchValue({
            consent: {
              consentDate : moment(this.pfc.consent.consentDate.value, "DD-MMM-YYY HH:mm").format(
                "DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm")
              }
          });
```

This throws error

```
 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'consentDate' of undefined.
```

Here consent is undefined. How can I update this form value ?

Comment: Seems this.pfc.consent is undefined. How value has been created?

Comment: What is this.pfc? I think the error is coming from here - this.pfc.consent.consentDate.value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly take value from form or get json value and use that. The issue seems to be with assigning value for pfc

```
const formData = this.participantForm.getRawValue();
this.participantForm.patchValue({
            consent: {
              consentDate : moment(formData.consent.consentDate, "DD-MMM-YYY HH:mm").format(
                "DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm")
              }
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to get form value.

```
this.participantForm.patchValue({
            consent: {
              consentDate : moment(this.pfc.get("consent").get("consentDate").value, "DD-MMM-YYY HH:mm").format(
                "DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm")
              }
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

If `this.pfc` maps to `this.participantForm.controls` which seems to be a formgroup. When you access `this.pfc.consent.consentDate.value`, you are trying to access (`this.pfc as FormGroup).consent`, which is undefined since `FormGroup` itself does not have the consent field. That is why you are getting the error.

To access the value properly, you need to use

```
this.pfc.value.consent.consentDate
```

or

```
this.pfc.get('consent.consentDate').value
```